# Error in IL Code using Reflection.Emit

Tags: c#, reflection.emit, il

I am writing a compiler that is generating .NET IL. I am writing it on Linux Mint using C#/Mono.

There is issue with some code that I am generating using Reflection.Emit. Please excuse the horrible names in the generated code. Below is the relevant part of the output from monodis.

```
.method public static 
       default valuetype Argon.30 Argon.28313529 (valuetype Argon.35 A_0)  cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x215c
// Code size 73 (0x49)
.maxstack 10
.locals init (
    valuetype Argon.35  V_0,
    valuetype Argon.35  V_1)
IL_0000:  ldarg.0 
IL_0001:  stloc.0 
IL_0002:  ldloca.s 0
IL_0004:  ldc.i4.7 
IL_0005:  newobj instance void valuetype Argon.35::'.ctor'(int32)
IL_000a:  call instance valuetype Argon.35 valuetype Argon.35::'add'(valuetype Argon.35)
IL_000f:  stloc.0 
IL_0010:  ldloc.0 
IL_0011:  stloc.1 
IL_0012:  ldloca.s 1
IL_0014:  ldc.i4.2 
IL_0015:  newobj instance void valuetype Argon.35::'.ctor'(int32)
IL_001a:  call instance valuetype Argon.35 valuetype Argon.35::'sub'(valuetype Argon.35)
IL_001f:  stloc.0 
IL_0020:  ldsfld class Argon.747970655F30 Argon.747970655F30::'instance'
IL_0025:  call valuetype Argon.30 Argon.283129()
IL_002a:  pop 
IL_002b:  ldarg.0 
IL_002c:  call valuetype Argon.30 Argon.28313229(valuetype Argon.35)
IL_0031:  pop 
IL_0032:  ldstr " + 5 = "
IL_0037:  newobj instance void class Argon.32::'.ctor'(string)
IL_003c:  call valuetype Argon.30 Argon.28313129(class Argon.32)
IL_0041:  pop 
IL_0042:  ldloc.0 
IL_0043:  call valuetype Argon.30 Argon.28313229(valuetype Argon.35)
IL_0048:  ret 
} // end of global method Argon.28313529
```

When I run this in mono I get the following error.

System.InvalidProgramException: Invalid IL code in :Argon.28313529 (Argon.35): IL_0048: ret

There appears to be no issue running this under Microsoft .NET. As I understand, that is due to mono performing the checks before optimizations.

Also, a previous version of the code without the error is below.

```
.method public static 
       default valuetype Argon.30 Argon.28313529 (valuetype Argon.35 A_0)  cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x215c
// Code size 46 (0x2e)
.maxstack 6
.locals init (
    valuetype Argon.35  V_0)
IL_0000:  ldarg.0 
IL_0001:  stloc.0 
IL_0002:  ldloca.s 0
IL_0004:  ldc.i4.7 
IL_0005:  newobj instance void valuetype Argon.35::'.ctor'(int32)
IL_000a:  call instance valuetype Argon.35 valuetype Argon.35::'add'(valuetype Argon.35)
IL_000f:  stloc.0 
IL_0010:  ldarg.0 
IL_0011:  call valuetype Argon.30 Argon.28313229(valuetype Argon.35)
IL_0016:  pop 
IL_0017:  ldstr " + 5 = "
IL_001c:  newobj instance void class Argon.32::'.ctor'(string)
IL_0021:  call valuetype Argon.30 Argon.28313129(class Argon.32)
IL_0026:  pop 
IL_0027:  ldloc.0 
IL_0028:  call valuetype Argon.30 Argon.28313229(valuetype Argon.35)
IL_002d:  ret 
} // end of global method Argon.28313529
```

Comment: Try verifying your code with PEVerify.exe from the .NET SDK. It may give you a better error message than Mono's verifier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aren't you leaving the instance of `Argon.747970655F30` put on the stack at `IL_0020`, in addition to the instance of `Argon.30` returned by the instruction at `IL_0043`? That would leave 2 items on the stack when you `ret`, rather than one.

Comment: This was the issue. The function was not being created as an instance method.

Answer (score 4):

The instruction at IL_0020 unbalances the stack, it should not have been emitted.  This looks like a bug in your language parser.  Equivalent to not reporting this kind of coding mistake:

```
class Example {
    Example instance;
    static void Method() { }
    void Bug() {
        instance.Method();    // CS0176
    }
}
```